# Can we perform scrolling using page object?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

Can we able to perform scrolling using Page Object??

Actually I need to ***scroll the web page*** (up / down) based on element. How can I perform using Page Object.

I'm Using Selenium web drive to launch the browser and using Page Object to automate the web page.

Any Suggestions???

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using

```
element.focus
```

Here is an element mapped, then using it's element to call focus:

```
text_field(:request_name, :id => 'request_name')
self.request_name_element.focus
self.request = "aaa"
```